# is AuthenticablePrincipal.LastLogon Property the LastLogOnTimeStamp value?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, active-directory

In `system.directoryservices.accountmanagement` the property `LastLogon` is the `LastLogOnTimeStampValue` replicated on all Domain's Domain Controllers or is the more recent values of LastLogon's property derived from the comparison of all available Domain's DC?

I can't find in MSDN where this property is taked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LastLogon` property of the `AuthenticablePrincipal` class reads the `lastLogonTimestamp` property from the Active Directory object. You can verify this by following the steps listed below:

1. Opening Active Directory Users and Computers MMC snapin on a domain controller.
2. Selct Advanced Features from the View menu.
3. Right click on the Active Directory object (user) which maps to your AuthenticablePrincipal object and choose properties.
4. Select the Attribute Editor tab. There you will find the `lastLogon` and `lastLogonTimestamp` attributes.

On my test system (.Net Framework 4.0, Active Directory 2008 R2) the `LastLogon` property of the `AuthenticablePrincipal` class maps to the `lastLogonTimestamp` property of the releated Active Directory object.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Be carefful, to test this you need an infrastructure with multiple DCs.

Comment: @JPBlanc: Why? Do you think the mapping of the AuthenticablePrincipal's LastLogon property to a Active Directory attribute is different in a multiple DC infrastructure?

Comment: @Hans- I've already do this test but why MSDN docs not tell us where this property is taked?

Comment: Just read carefully @sq33G answer you can also read [The lastLogon attribute is not updated when a client computer runs an LDAP simple bind operation against a Windows Server 2003-based domain controller](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;939899) which explain why this attribute is built for.

Comment: @JPBlanc: Yes, I know. But the question was to which Attribute in Active Directory the LastLogon property of AuthenticablePrincipal machtes. Please, see Christian's comment to sq33G answer.

Comment: @Christian: I don't know why Microsoft does not document this. Please note that you could also use the AuthenticablePrincipal class against a local user account database.

Comment: @Hans: I know it, but my question was intended in a Domain scope. I'll apcet your answer in a few hours just to see if someone have a link to some microsoft document that explain this property where take his value!

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is: it's not that simple.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/01/27/dandelions-vcr-clocks-and-last-logon-times-these-are-a-few-of-our-least-favorite-things.aspx

If you need better accuracy than +-14 days, you're going to have your work cut out for you.

Comment: -this is not answering my question. I've already do the work for retrieving the true user's lastlogon property using LDAP on any available DC and doing comparison. -need to know if accountmanagement class do this! Thanks you for you effort.

Comment: Did you see the Community Content on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.lastlogon(v=VS.100).aspx)?

Comment: Yes is the first thing I've see. But isn't a microsoft doc. I've voted up you answer. Many Thanks